# Help showing this is an equivalence relation

Tags: relations

I need help with question as following:

1. $X= \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ 
   I need to define the relation $R$ on $X$ as follows:

   $(X_1,X_2)R(Y_1,Y_2) \longleftrightarrow (X_1)^2+(X_2)^2=(Y_1)^2+(Y_2)^2$

Can you prove it using (X)R(Y) ?

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give you some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people are much more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: @akerman What parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: @akerman: Start with the *definition* of an equivalence relation. Can you state what it is you *need* to show in order to establish that $R$ is an equivalence relation?

Comment: Note that $(X_1,X_2)R(Y_1,Y_2)$ if and only the corresponding points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ lie at the same distance from the origin $(0,0)$. Don't you expect this to be an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For describing the equivalence class, think about using cross-multiplication to determine if two fractions are equal.